# Confidence interval for a Sum approximated with the central limit theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem, confidence-interval

According to the central limit theorem: $S\approx N(n*\mu, n*\sigma^2)$
Normally, a confidence interval is calculated according to:
$(μ \pm 1.96*\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}})$
Do you divide $\sigma^2$ by n in the case of an approximation of the sum?
I have seen cases, where the interval is calculated as:
$(μ \pm 1.96*\sqrt{\sigma^2})$

What is the right way to calculated the confidence interval in this case? Is the approach without n wrong or does it apply to some cases?

Thank you

Comment: For a normally distributed random variable $(μ \pm 1.96*\sqrt{\sigma^2})$ suggests an interval with $95\%$ probability of containing a particular observation. $(μ \pm 1.96*\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}})$ suggests an interval with $95\%$ probability of containing the mean of $n$ independent observations.   $(nμ \pm 1.96*\sqrt{n\sigma^2})$ suggests an interval with $95\%$ probability of containing the sum of $n$ independent observations.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your answer! :)
So if I have to estimate θ using a confident interval, which of these "formulas" do I have to use? The first one?
Thank you :)

Comment: What is $\theta?$

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion about the distinction between $\mu$ and its estimate $\bar X,$ between cases where the numerical value of $\sigma$ is and is not known, and between sample size $n$ and $4.$ Perhaps the following step-by-step approach will help.

If data are a random sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ where the second argument is the standard deviation, then

$$\bar X_n = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{X_i}{n}
\sim \mathsf{Norm}\left(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

Thus a 95% confidence interval (CI) for $\mu$ (when the numerical value of $\sigma$ is known) is of the form
$$\bar X_n \pm 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},$$
where 1.96 cuts probability 0.025 from the upper tail
of the (symmetrical) standard normal distribution.

Notice that the center of this CI is the *sample mean* $\bar X_n,$ which estimates the population mean $\mu.$

Furthermore, if $\sigma$ is unknown and estimated by the *sample* standard deviation
$S_n = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i=\bar X_n)^2},$ then
a 95% CI for $\mu$ is of the form
$$\bar X_n \pm t^*\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}},$$
where $t^*$ cuts probability 0.025 from the upper tail
of Student's t distribution (also symmetrical) with degrees of freedom $\nu = n-1.$

Finally, if you are dealing with $T_4 = \sum_{i=1}^4 X_i,$ then $T_4\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_4 = 4\mu, \sigma_4 = 4\sigma).$ So if you want a 95% CI for $E(T_4) = \mu_4 = 4\mu,$ then you simply multiply by $4$ the endpoints of the corresponding CI for $\mu.$ In the case where the
numerical value of $\sigma$ is known, this would be:

$$4\bar X_n \pm 1.96\frac{4\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

In particular, if $n = 4,$ then the CI becomes

$$T_4 \pm 1.96\sqrt{4\sigma^2},$$
which agrees with @Henry's first comment,